# Marking a custom coroutine dispatcher so that it is treated like Dispatchers.IO

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines

I am using a simple class to inject dispatchers to my objects, so I can have different dispatchers for testing and for actual work, the classes I use are :

```
interface IDispatchers {
    val IO: CoroutineDispatcher
    val CPU: CoroutineDispatcher
    val UI: CoroutineDispatcher
}

object AppDispatchers  : IDispatchers{
    override val UI = Dispatchers.Main
    override val CPU = Dispatchers.Default
    override val IO = Dispatchers.IO
}

@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
object TestDispatchers : IDispatchers {
    override val IO = Dispatchers.Unconfined
    override val CPU = Dispatchers.Unconfined
    override val UI = Dispatchers.Unconfined
}
```

this works great and does exactly what I want.

my problem is with the latest update of android studio, when I have an operation that could be blocking (for example reading from a stream) it cannot understand that I am indeed using an IO dispatcher and it keeps showing a message

for example let's say I have this class:

```
class fooViewModel(val dispatchers:IDispatchers) {

    suspend fun thisDoesStuffOnIO() {
        //code
        val nextLine = withContext(dispatchers.IO) { stream.readLine() }

        //more code
    } 

}
```

now when I replace `dispatchers.IO` with the actual `Dispatchers.IO` it shows no warning, but when I go back to my implementation it shows a warning

I tried looking for an annotation or property in `Dispatchers.IO` that ,if copied to my interface, would disable the inspection but I couldn't find any

so is there a way to make that inspection understand that the dispatcher I am using is indeed an IO dispatcher and there is no actual problem?

Comment: I seriously doubt there's a fix for this. In my code I just added annotation to supress that check. =/

Comment: that's what I do, but when I add it to the file I'm afraid I will miss some io operation and not change its context but adding it to each statement makes it kind of tiresome :/ I guess I'll have to stick to that, thank you